# How to get Amazon Redshift working on PGADMIN 3/ PostgreSQL , when I have postgresql versions 9.3 and 8.4 installed?

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

I am new to Ubuntu , primarily worked on Windows. Need to install two separate versions of PostgreSQL so that I can connect to Amazon Redshift server via PGADMIN UI.

*UPDATE : I got the feedback from community. Thank you all for notifying my error in asking this question. I have tried to explain my problem in great detail below*

### STEP 1 : Trying to connect to Redshift using current PGADMIN v1.20

So basically , I want to connect to an Amazon Redshift cluster, where the events which I need to monitor are stored.

the server goes something like this: mobileanalyticsautoexport...........redshift.amazonaws.com (can't reveal the whole name for obvious reasons). Port number is 8192.

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 on my system with postgreSQL version 9.3.10 (To be precise : "PostgreSQL 9.3.10 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit"). 
When I try to connect to the server with read-only credentials provided to me, I get the following errors:

```
An error has occurred
17:05:38: Error: ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "client_min_messages" to "notice".
17:06:00: Error: Column not found in pgSet: "datlastsysoid"
17:06:47: Error: Column not found in pgSet: datlastsysoid
An assertion failed : db/pgSet.cpp(373): assert "col < nCols && col >= 0" failed in GetOid().
17:07:18: Error: Column not found in pgSet: oid
an assertion failed :db/pgSet.cpp(373): assert "col < nCols && col >= 0" failed in GetOid().
17:08:32: Error: Column not found in pgSet: encoding
An assertion failed:db/pgSet.cpp(248): assert "col < nCols && col >= 0" failed in GetVal().
An assertion failed: db/pgSet.cpp(234): assert "col < nCols && col >= 0" failed in GetCharPtr().
17:09:24: Warning: The server you are connecting to is not a version that is supported by this release of pgAdmin III.
pgAdmin III may not function as expected.
Supported server versions are 8.4 to 9.5.
```

and lastly :

```
An error has occurred:
17:09:52: Error: ERROR:  must be superuser to examine "default_tablespace"
```

Usually , I just proceed by click 'ok' for all of them till I arrive at the very last error:

```
An error has occurred:
15:21:25: Error: ERROR:  must be superuser to examine "default_tablespace".
```

After that , I am not able to run the SQL query tool (it is grey-ed out)in-spite of the server being added to my list of servers.

I then went to the Amazon Redshift documentation where the following is stated :

> Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL 8.0.2. Amazon Redshift and
>   PostgreSQL have a number of very important differences that you must
>   be aware of as you design and develop your data warehouse
>   applications.
>
> link:://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html

### Step 2 : Downloading an older version of PostgreSQL

So , I decided to download the postgreSQL version 8.0.2 . I used the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-8.0.2
```

which was unsuccessful (logs below):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-8.0.2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-8.0.2'
```

so I went onto the next best thing expected to work :

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-8.4
```

and it installed.

### Step 3: Changing the port number of postgreSQL 8.4

Now that I have two versions of postgreSQL , I decided to change the port number of the postgreSQL to version 8.4 in the postgresql.conf file by using :

```
sudo vim postgresql.conf
```

pressed `I` for insert mode 
then deleted port 5432 and made it port 8192 , pressed escape , `:x` and then I quit.

I also went back to the file to verify that the port number has indeed changed and it had changed to 8192. 
After doing this , I restarted my PGADMIN and tried to connect to the Redshift server using the same credentials. It shows the same error as before , nothing has changed.

### My problem statement

Therefore , I believe my real question is:

**How can I get Amazon Redshift working on PostgreSQL, when I have versions 9.3 and 8.4 installed?**

### Extras: Tried on MacBook

P.S. : I tried the exact same credentials on MacBook with Psequel and it connected in one shot. No issues at all there.

Comment: I recommend going through the steps and trying some of what you're trying to do first, and then coming back here or serverfault or askubuntu with a better basis in what you need.

Comment: Hi  I have made the requested changes and added what I have tried to do till now. Can somebody help me ? Thank you !! Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: You have added a lot more detail to the question, that is great!  Please format your code, commands, etc, using the code block tool button: `{}`.  I have done a little of this as an example, and leave the rest as an exercise for the author.  In addition, you now have a long question, which could really use being broken up into logical sections to make it readable and solveable.  At that point I, personally, will vote to re-open.

Comment: @Kzqai: Thanks !! Formatted the question and divided the information logically. Hope this is good enough :) .

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use two servers running on a single machine. The instances just need to use a different port. In PgAdmin you can then make connections to the two servers, both using the same IP address but a different port.